# Should I put a lot of initialization work in constructor or in a member method?

Tags: c++

Should I put a lot of initialization work in constructor or in a member method ?

```
 class A {
 public:
    A() {
        //a lot of initialization work...
    }
    ~A() = default;
    //or put those work in it
    void init() {
        /*
         After creating object of this class, I invoke
         init method to do some heavy initialization work...
        */
    }
 }
```

Comment: I really depends on your use case. Its often better to initialize the object completely in the constructor, then you can be sure it is always in a valid state, you could also potentially make the object immutable. If you need to wait for some reason to initialize then the member function is better.

Comment: assignment is not initialization

Comment: What do you mean by lot of initialization?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava Initializing context for a library, do some work for object is valid to use,...

Comment: A default constructor _usually_ should do the minimum work necessary to make the object valid. That means there is no requirement on the part of a user to call "init()" to make it valid.  That being said, I voted to close this question, because it is the kind that elicits many opinions while having no clearly correct answer.

Comment: What do the class objects stands for if their initialization is meaningless? A public `init` function is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @StoryTeller I mean initialization work like creating context for some library to work, or do some computation for the future use of member method, all it should put in constructor? Those works are heavy and I think it should be put in a member method.

Comment: The whole notion of constructors is to bind proper initialization to object lifetime. The language does that to reduce programming errors. There is no way to guarantee `init` will be called from outside the class, but a c'tor is **always** called when an object is created. Constructors are for initialization, not "just for light initialization". They are executable functions like any other. Work with the tools, not against them.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you :), that's great to me. I heard some opinions that c'tor should do the minimum work, but why ?

Comment: @Hope - I think it's just a common good practice that is being warped. The best c'tors are the ones you don't need to write explicitly. For instance, if your `A` needs to use some file, it'd be better to use a smaller, more focused class, that opens and closes those types of files (let's call it `F`). That way, instead of holding a raw file handle, `A` will hold a member of type `F`, and initializing that member can be done in the member initializer list (passing arguments to the `F` c'tor). The net result is that on the face of it, the c'tor of `A` looks shorter, because it delegates.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's the same amount of work, except it's properly distributed between objects. OOP in a nutshell, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like the following way of looking at this, but, as mentioned at the bottom of this post, it has a single, massive, drawback:

The constructor's job is to establish the **class invariant**.

A **class invariant** is the description of the legal state a class can be in in between calls to public member functions, and each and every public member function should be well-behaved for any and all possible invariant state. So it's always a good idea to keep your class invariants as strict as possible.

In light of all this: the amount of work being done in a constructor should be whatever is needed to set up as strict an invariant as reasonably possible for the class.

For example:

If I have a class that holds a pointer to an OS window:

```
class Window {
  native_window* w_;
  ...
};
```

The class invariant could be "w_ is always either null, or points to an instance of a window.", but that's annoying, since it means that most member functions will have to perform a null check. If the invariant was "w_ points to a valid window handle", then you can rely on that assumption and greatly simplify the rest of the class.

However! This means that should the constructor fail to establish an invariant (the OS call to create the window failed because of reasons), then the only way you can handle the failure is to throw an exception. So if you are operating in a codebase where exceptions are not permitted, then this whole approach to class design is moot.

Comment: I would like to add that check in other member function may not be needed. like  `std::vector::front()`.